# Firebase module not found

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have followed the instructions for adding firebase to an iOS project for Firebase 3. I have opened the workspace in xcode but when I add the import for Firebase, it says "no such module Firebase".

As the previous quickstart projects are deprecated, I don't have a working example to compare to.

Can someone point me in the right direction or to a working example?

Comment: See https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios, which is the working app from which many of the samples in the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/start) take their code.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Failed on the first one I tried: $ pod install
Analyzing dependencies
[!] Unable to find a specification for `FirebaseUI`

Answer (score 2):

The setup instructions say to use pod 'Firebase'.
I changed to this:
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'

and it is happy now.

Comment: Are you able to get analytics this way? In the documentation it says Analytics lives in 'Firebase/Core'

Answer (score 1):

Adding ${SRCROOT}/Pods/Firebase/CoreOnly/Sources into the target's "Header search paths" fixed the problem. Steps:

1.Select your target

2.Go to Build Settings

3.Search for header search path

4.Add ${SRCROOT}/Pods/Firebase/CoreOnly/Sources

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you might not get analytics by changing it by doing that, changing your podFile to include this helped me

target 'yourProject' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

# Pods for yourProject

pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'

target 'yourProjectTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

target 'yourProjectUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end